# Neutron population growth in a reactor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, neutrons

In nuclear reactors physics, the effective constant $k_{eff}$ is defined as

$$k_\text{eff} \equiv {\text{number of neutrons in one generation}\over \text{number of neutrons in the preceding genereation}}$$

And the equation that describes the change of the neutron population, the point-kinetics equation, can be obtained as

> Consider a core in which the neutron cycle takes $l$ seconds to
>   complete. The change $\Delta n$ in the total number of thermal
>   neutrons in one cycle at time t is $(k_\text{eff}-1)n(t)$, where $n(t)$ is
>   the number of neutrons at the beginning of the cycle. Thus $$\Delta
>  n(t) \equiv l {dn(t) \over dt} = (k_\text{eff}-1) n(t) $$

(Fundamentals of Nuclear Science & Engineering by John K. Shultis, Richard E. Faw, Chapter 6.1)

which solution  is 
$$n(t) = n_0 \exp{\left[{k_\text{eff}-1\over l} t\right]}$$

so if we now calculate the rate between the population in one generation and the preceding we have

$${n(2l) \over n(l)} = e^{k_\text{eff}-1} $$

that only coincides with the first definition of $k_\text{eff}$ at first order.

Where is the condition $k_\text{eff} \rightarrow 1$ in the derivation of the point-kinetics equation, so both results are equal?

Comment: I think you should check your math. First order expansion of $ e^{k_{eff}-1}$ is $k_{eff}$.

Comment: I didn't want to say Otherwise. Maybe is not clear, but the question is why the rate between two generations obtained with the result of the point kinetics equation only is equal to the definition of $k_{eff}$ at first order.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay if the two results are equal only at first order.  The implicit assumption is that the length $\ell$ of the "neutron cycle time" is short enough that the higher-order terms are negligible.  This is the standard calculus technique for deriving the exponential function; it shows up all over the place.

Note that if $k_\text{eff} \lesssim 1$ then the reaction dies away, and if $k_\text{eff} \gtrsim 1$ the reactor explodes, so $k_\text{eff} \approx 1$ is the case of interest for nuclear engineering anyway.